# When cloning an item, is it possible to change ALL the inputs attributes and IDs as this;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[**Codepen link to see in action**](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/qEayNV?editors=101)

Suppose I have this **markup:**

```
<div class="wrapper-1">
  <input id="name-1" class="name-input" type="text" name="name"/>
  <input id="surname-1" type="text" name="surnamename"/>
  <input id="telephone-1" type="text" name="telephone"/>
  <input id="email-1" type="text" name="email"/>
  <input id="comments-1" type="text" name="comments"/>
</div>

<button>Clone me</button>
```

And this **JavaScript** to handle the cloning

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var d = $('div');
  var counter = d.length;
  var newCounter = new Number(counter + 1);
  var cloned = $('.wrapper-' + counter).clone().attr('class', 'wrapper-' + newCounter).fadeIn('slow');

  //Finding items that need to have different ID
  cloned.find('.name-input').attr('id', '#name-' + newCounter);

  //Cloning
  $('.wrapper-' + counter).after(cloned);
});
```

As you can see, ID counter of the input with class`.name-input` changes along with the wrapper's counter.

But if I want to change the name of it, and also all the IDs and names of 4 lower inputs, I have to manually insert and duplicate the same code:

`cloned.find('.name-input').attr('id', '#name-' + newCounter);`

*And imagine I have 25 of them.*

**So my question is:**

Is it possible to insert something like this:

`cloned.find('input').attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + '-' + newCounter);`

I mean so as browser automatically would parse the names and IDs of the elements and add the the `counter` variable to them.

Surely in this given example `$(this)` will refer to the element that fired the event - `button`, but maybe this approach is kinda possible?

Comment: You can nest that in the `.each()` loop :)

Comment: @Terry Could you please demonstrate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the jQuery `each()` function does, for example:

```
var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');

cloned.find('input').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', buttonId + '-' + newCounter);
});
```

The code inside the `each()` function is executed for each element in the set. Inside this function, `this` refers to the element the code is currently being applied to.

There are other jQuery functions that work similarly, like `filter()`.